# Getting "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name:"

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I know there are a tons of this title on several posts but having browsed through some of them, I have not found any the helps with my issue.

I am trying to build a dropdownlist in Repeater control that is dynamically populated with data from the database.

Here is the code I am using:

//markup

State:

//codefile

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myconstring"].ToString());
        string sSQL = "Select stateID, sateName from Mytable ORDER By stateName ASC";
            SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand(sSQL, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader dtrClient = cmd6.ExecuteReader();
            DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)Repeater2.Controls[Repeater2.Controls.Count - 1].FindControl("ddlstate");
            ddl.DataSource = dtrClient;
            ddl.DataTextField = "stateName";
            ddl.DataValueField = "stateID";
            ddl.DataBind();
```

When I run it, I get the following error message:

Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
 Parameter name: index

on the following line:

**DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)Repeater2.Controls[Repeater2.Controls.Count - 1].FindControl("ddlstate");**

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**UPDATE:**

```
     State: <asp:DropDownList ID="aircraftstate" runat="server" style="width:150px;" AppendDataBoundItems="True">
     <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
     </asp:DropDownList> 



    //We query the DB only once in the Page Load
     SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstr"].ToString());
     string sSQL = "Select StateID, StateName from MyTable ORDER By sName ASC";
     SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand(sSQL, con);
     con.Open();
     table = new DataTable();
     table.Load(cmd3.ExecuteReader());

   //We load the DropDownList in the event
    protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("aircraftstate");
        ddl.DataSource = table;
        ddl.DataTextField = "StateName";
        ddl.DataValueField = "StateID";
        ddl.DataBind();
```

Comment: Is `Repeater2.Controls.Count` 0 by chance? You might be trying to do `Repeater2.Controls[-1]`. You should probably check for an empty result set and handle it appropriately.

Comment: Have you checked my answer @Kenny?

Comment: @kbok.

Sorry for late response. I had an emergency and I am about to check it now.

Looks awesome though. Thanks so much. I have been struggling for this Repeater dropdownlist for a while. Will be back shortly.

Comment: @kblok, please take a look at updated code above. No errors which is always good but the dropdownlist is not getting populated.

Am I missing something?

Comment: @kblok, Ok, it is working. Great job!

I was missing repeater_ItemDataBound on the markup. I guess my question is, if I have two dropdownlists which I do, do I add both to the repeater_ItemDataBound event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Repeater is a templated based control you should `Find` your DropDownList and populate it in the `ItemDataBound` event. 
So you could do something like this:

```
DataTable table;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //We query the DB only once in the Page Load
    string sSQL = "Select stateID, sateName from Mytable ORDER By stateName ASC";
    SqlCommand cmd6 = new SqlCommand(sSQL, con);
    con.Open();
    table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(cmd6.ExecuteReader());

}

//We load the DropDownList in the event
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    var ddl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlID");
    ddl.DataSource = table;
    ddl.DataTextField = "stateName";
    ddl.DataValueField = "stateID";
    ddl.DataBind();

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Short and sweet solution.